# What does すごいこと考えるわね mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, reading-comprehension

Context: 2 characters talking about what do to with an enemy after defeated him

> G1: この者が、目が覚めたら私達のことを報告されるだけだろう。
> それとも、ここで息の根を止めておくか？ 口封じに。
>
> G2:だから、ダメですよそんな。
>
> G1:分かってる。では連れていくしかないだろう。
> 目が覚めたら、ゆっくり話を聞いてもらう必要はあるかもしれないな。
> いや……あるいは、もしもの時、人質として警察との交渉として使えるかもしれない...
>
> G1:すごいこと考えるわね。あんた

What does すごいこと考えるわね mean in this sentence?
My guess is "You are thinking too far"? If you can please share your English translation of the last sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

すごい is basically a positive word that means "great" or "wonderful", but here it is used a little sarcastically to mean "surprising", "amazing", "incredible", "crazy", etc. You can translate that sentence as "What an idea" or something. Or "What a great idea..." may be okay if the reader can understand it's a sarcastic remark.